# Snowflake Python connection using externalbrowser authenticator

Tags: python, authentication, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have code to connect to Snowflake through Python using external browser authentication (`authenticator` parameter set to `'externalbrowser'`)

I also have installed `snowflake-connector-python` version `2.3.5`

On my machine running snowflake.connector.connect displays the following message, but doesn't open any browser windows to do the authentication:
"Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again..."

On my old machine it displays the same message, but opens a browser window to log in. What do you think can be causing this problem, and what can I do to fix this? Am I missing a package?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you found a way to fix this? I've tried Sharvan's answer but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You want to try the troubleshooting suggested by Snowflake blog here [EXTERNAL BROWSER SSO FROM CONNECTOR FAILS ON REDIRECT BACK TO LOCALHOST](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/External-browser-SSO-from-connector-fails-on-redirect-back-to-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by allowing the pop up in your browser in the system settings

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same issue, and do not set parameter "authenticator" to 'externalbrowser', if its optional you can remove this parameter and test.

after i remove "authenticator" parameter from my config file, I was able to authneticate and establish connection to snowflake.